# UITabBarItem and its UIViewController - a complex issue

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a bit of complex issue with a `UITabBarItem` it's `UIViewController`. 
 Basically I have a series of `UIButtons` which is a layer on top of UITabBar, if the a `UIButton` is selected the right `UITabBarItem` is selected. 
The complex issue starts when I have a `UIViewController` that is displayed when one of the `UITabBarItem` is pressed this takes the whole screen and displays a series of `UIButtons`. Once you press a button it returns back to the `UITabBarItem` selected but what I want in the `UIViewcontroller` is to have a dynamic `UIView`. I can get everything else working except that because the `viewDidLoad` is pre-loaded within that view. 
Any suggestions. Sorry if that was a mouthful!

Comment: are you creating `UIView`'s dynamically or in the same interface builder?

Comment: I tried both ways but It doesn't work. I have is a value (for which button is pressed) that is being passed to the UIViewcontroller to displayed the dynamic UIViews but since it thing is viewDidLoad it is always zero. I have tried other methods and loadView also. I really need help in this.

Comment: I usually dont suggest `UITabBar` for this kind of use, you can better use `UISegmented` for the tabs effect. Well if you still want the help in the same `UITabBar` scenario then kindly post your code here or mail me personally so we can help you more accordingly.

Comment: You have totally gone of the point. Let me put it to in a simple way so you understand. I have 5 Tab Bars. When I click the last one it displays a view with a series of buttons, which is basically like menu. What I actually want is if I click on one of those buttons the View inside the Tab to change. Something like this app: uk.westfield.com/london/offers-events/iphone

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand what you are asking, it seems that you need the view within the fifth tab to change based on what button is pressed - you can achieve this by making a bunch of graphic buttons to fill the view, then to have the fullscreen overlay you need to have your view present the new view as a modal view controller.

```
[self presentModalViewController:controllerForButton1 animated:NO]
```

This actually doesn't have much to with tab bars, this just happens to be within a tab bar controller, and they used the fifth view to hold a big menu, because there weren't enough tabs to suit their need.

Comment: That's not what I want and there is similar app available.

Comment: Ok well tell us what you want then? What exactly is a "dynamic UIView" to you? Dynamic is a broad term when you're programming in objective-c, I would say that 100% of my views are dynamic in that they don't always display the exact same content, some less dynamic in that they reuse the same set of subviews.

Comment: Let me put it to in a simple way so you understand. I have 5 Tab Bars. When I click the last one it displays a view with a series of buttons, which is basically like menu. What I actually want is if I click on one of those buttons the View inside the Tab to change. Something like this app: http://uk.westfield.com/london/offers-events/iphone/